# Remove current directory from clang include path

Tags: c, compiler-errors, clang

I am using ArmClang and I want to remove the current directory from the include path. According to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#include-path-management):

> -I-, --include-barrier
>
> Restrict all prior -I flags to double-quoted inclusion and remove current directory from include path

However, using both of these options I get:

```
ArmClang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead
```

However the `-iquote` option doesn't have the effect of removing the current directory form the include path, is there another way to do this?